# Entity Framework 6 "HasRequired" and "WithMany" partially working - not working as expected

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

So after going crazy for 3 hours and looking everywhere on the web I forced myself to ask here. I have been using Entity Framework for more than 5 years and I never had the kind of problem that I describe below

I have two POCO classes (edited):

```
public class Company
{
    public virtual ICollection<BusinessUnit> BusinessUnits { get; protected set; } = new List<BusinessUnit>();

    public int Id { get; protected set; }
}

public class BusinessUnit
{
    public virtual Company Company { get; protected set; } = new Company();

    public int CompanyId { get; protected set; }

    public string Description { get; protected set; }
}
```

And in my "BusinessUnit" configuration I declare:

```
        this
            .HasRequired(c => c.Company)
            .WithMany(c => c.BusinessUnits)
            .HasForeignKey(c => c.CompanyId);
```

The following works:

- Individually query the 2 entities through their DbSets
- Accessing the N to 1 "Company" navigation property on my "BusinessUnit" retrieved entity

The following does not work:

- The 1 to N "BusinessUnits" navigation property on the retrieved "Company" entity is always NULL, even if using "Include" to do eager loading

What I am already doing that, according to EF guides and my experience, is correct:

- Lazy loading is enabled (the 1 navigation works indeed)
- Proxies are enabled (same as above)
- The ICollection is virtual so lazy loading is enabled for it
- The "HasRequired" part of the mapping is working, I can access the "Company" proxy on the "BusinessUnit" entity

I have tried changing the property setters to public, but still does not work/fix the problem

This has no apparent reason to misbehave. I am clearly missing something but I can't figure out what.

Entitfy Framerowk version in use is 6.1.3 on .Net 4.6, installed through NuGet package.

Comment: Could you post the rest of the code in a self contained example? I am interested in the complete mapping code.

Comment: Did you try to initialize `BusinessUnits` inside the constructor of the `Company` class?

Comment: @YacoubMassad yes, to no avail

Comment: @Igor ok, I'm adding it now

Comment: I tried your code on my machine and I could not reproduce the problem. Can you provide a reproducible example?

Comment: I tried you code also like @YacoubMassad and I it worked properly https://gist.github.com/AlbertoMonteiro/e4eb399baa18450fa3ff

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem seems to be caused by the new [initializers for auto-property](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/New-Language-Features-in-C%23-6#initializers-for-auto-properties) feature of C# 6.

If you initialize the properties "inline" Entity Framework breaks on one to many relationships.

Remove the initializers and the navigation properties should work again.

```
public class Company
{
    public virtual ICollection<BusinessUnit> BusinessUnits { get; protected set; }

    public int Id { get; protected set; }
}

public class BusinessUnit
{
    public virtual Company Company { get; protected set; }

    public int CompanyId { get; protected set; }

    public string Description { get; protected set; }
}
```

Comment: That's the problem indeed, although it would be great to understand why it happens. I forgot to add my initializers when I posted this originally because I thought they wouldn't matter, then I edited to add them to provide a more detailed scenario to reproduce the problem. Thanks.

Comment: @MatteoMosca please mark as "correct answer" to provide credits/points to Albireo